# nVidia Graphics Card not working

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

My nVidia GeForce GT520M graphics card suddenly not working... Now I played games with Intel HD graphics card, it is so laggy. I tried to download and reinstall but it still the same. I had set the game(and other application) to run with nVidia graphics card in `nVidia Control Panel`. When I check the `nVidia GPU Activity`, it always tell me 'None'. Before it will tell me my game is running with nVidia but now not.

Comment: is your Nvidia card listed in the device manager?

Comment: Yes...idk why it is not working

Comment: Are you using the current release of the Nvidia drivers?  Does the device manager indicate the same information?

Comment: Now i am using the latest driver. Ya, the device manager indicate the same information?

Comment: Can you test the card in a spare system?

Comment: How to test it?

Answer (score 0):

If it is suddenly not working then there cannot be an issue with the drivers since it was working fine with the earlier drivers. You have mentioned that you updated the drivers after the card stopped working. This suggests it could very well be a hardware issue or an operating system issue.

Comment: DAGS for GT520M Failure - sounds like more Nvidia bad BGA failures (look, Ma, it doesn't just kill MacBook Pros!) Or read this: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Nvidia-GPU-failure,6248.html

Comment: no, i didn't update the driver. It just suddenly not working. after tha i update my driver but same

Comment: yes, that's why it can't be a driver issue, it must have something to do with the hardware or the os